# Mathematical Operation with non-unique index

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if the following applies only to `groupby().apply()`, but that's where I catch the following error when trying to divide a dataframe by a series when both have the same (but non-unique) index:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

This is how I get there: I start with a `df` like

```
     country code  patents  year        POP         tcgdp        rgdpl 
0  Argentina   AR    26128  1963  21616.403  23532.842578  5779.541172   
1  Argentina   AR    21296  1964  21949.244  26581.915354  6163.149818   
2  Argentina   AR    20656  1965  22283.100  30364.930885  6692.229491   
3  Argentina   AR    18058  1966  22611.604  30579.084323  6607.346553   
4  Argentina   AR    15632  1967  22934.225  32721.004053  6710.778328
```

and do

```
df = df.sort(['country', 'year'])
df.set_index(['country'], inplace=True)

def create_diffs(group, columns):
    diff = group.iloc[1:][columns] - group.iloc[:-1][columns]
    time_intvall = group.iloc[1:]['year'] - group.iloc[:-1]['year']
    return diff.div(time_intvall)

columns = ['patents', 'POP', 'tcgdp', 'rgdpl']
df.groupby(level=0).apply(create_diffs, columns)
```

on `pandas 0.14`. Even if `div()` requires unique indices, at least the `/` operator or similar should allow division by order - or do i have to recast these into numpy arrays?

Any other comment on the structure of the code, which is supposed to create differences over time, is welcome.

*As an additional feedback from myself*: **chrisb**'s comment on `diff()` also applies to the year. `year.iloc[1:] - year.iloc[:-1]` returns `0` everywhere (and one `NaN`), since it sorts the value again by the index.

Comment: seems like you should be setting the index on country and year.

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to access `year` inside my function, which I need to compute the time difference

Comment: In that case don't set the index, and use `df.groupby('country')`

Comment: alternatively you can use `df.set_index(['country', 'year'], drop=False)`

Comment: @ZJS I have the habit of setting the indices I groupby, since that makes attaching the result of the `apply()` to the original dataframe very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want this code to work, just replace the return with this, which uses the numpy divide function, which will broadcast on shape and not try to match indicies:

```
np.divide(diff, pd.DataFrame(time_intvall))
```

One other thing, this line

```
group.iloc[1:][columns] - group.iloc[:-1][columns]
```

Only happens to work because every index in the `group` Dataframe is identical, normally it would not, because that data will be aligned by index.  The better way to wright this would probably be:

```
diff = group[columns] - group[columns].shift(1)
diff = diff.iloc[1:]  # or diff.dropna()
```

Comment: @FooBar, it worked for me, but didn't when I tried with a different shape.  I think `np.divide(diff, pd.DataFrame(time_intvall))` should always work.

Comment: If you wrap the Series in a DataFrame, the shape will be `(16,1)` and the broadcasting should work?